# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated false when using WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp

Tags: forms-authentication, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack with ClientHttp web request mode and when I try to check if the user is currently logged in (for sometime I'll need a bridge between asp.net authentication and SS one) I got false for IsAuthenticated...I've configured my service client this way

```
            jsonServiceClient = new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient(BaseAddressHelper.GetBasePathWithApiPath());

            jsonServiceClient.ShareCookiesWithBrowser = true;
            jsonServiceClient.UseBrowserHttpHandling = false;
            jsonServiceClient.StoreCookies = true;
```

But when I'm on the Service I got false... if I use                 jsonServiceClient.UseBrowserHttpHandling = true; that part is ok but when I got an exception I don't get it deserialized correctly.. anyone of you got the same problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've found a solution and it's to put this in web.config.. <system.serviceModel>        
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />    
</system.serviceModel>